# Good Image file size limit

Tags: php, file, upload

What is today a proper file sze limit when letting users upload images.
The images will be resized but don't know what a good limit would be.

Comment: Is there any context you can give us? How are these images going to be used?

Comment: Too wide scoped a question, are these images for the web like imgur, or storage & printing like flickr?

Answer (score 5):

Depends on the final use of the image, server resources available, type of images and expected tech level of your users.

example: If you're expecting lots of images uploaded directly from digital photos then your limit will be in the 5M to 10M range.  Most users will take images directly off their cameras and not attempt to resize before uploading to a website.

It really boils down to the questions I started with.

Comment: images will be used in gallery: resized to 1024*800, not sure about resources available but would guess there is enough space and it will be resized. but the thech level of the users is probabely low...

Comment: Then I would probably start with a 10M limit and see how that works.  Create a log every time the upload is rejected due to exceeding limits.  This will tell you over time if your limit needs to be raised to better support your users.